# Multipole moment of an octupole

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics, multipole-expansion

I have a cube with each side of length *a* centered on the origin. Each of the corners carries a charge of magnitude *q*, but the sign of the charge alternates such that no edge connects corners with the same polarity of charges. This is obviously what I call "a lengthy description of an octupole".

I know that being an octupole, it will only have an octupole moment but I was wondering how to find them from the spherical harmonic expansion of multipole moments. The problem I face is that spherical harmonic expansion of multipoles are given as an integral but I here have discrete charges. How can I go from integral form of the spherical harmonic expansion to the discrete version?

Comment: Write your charge density as a sum of 8 [Dirac delta functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).

Comment: Could you please explain more? Since the charges are all at the same distance from the origin (=$sqrt(3)a/2$) wont that equal 8*$delta$(r-$sqrt(3)a/2$

Comment: You would need Dirac functions in 3-dimensional space: $\delta(\vec{r}-\vec{r}_0)$
which is short-hand notation for $\delta(x-x_0)\delta(y-y_0)\delta(z-z_0)$.